# Front-End stopped working after magento upgrade

Tags: css, upgrade, magento2.2.6, static-content-deploy

Front-end stopped working after a 2.2.6 upgrade. As you can see on screenshots, there is something wrong with the styles-m.css file.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to regenerate the static content by doing the below steps -

1. Delete all folders under pub/static
2. Delete var/cache
3. Delete var/composer_home
4. Delete var/generation
5. Delete var/page_cache
6. Delete var/view_preprocessed

Now open your command prompt and go to your root installation of magento 2 and run the following command

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Your answer gave me a light. I had to add " -f pt_BR "at the end of this command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and it worked. Thank you!